# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular

Below is my form. Works fine during `ng serve -o`. No issues raised. No errors raised.

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customerName">Your Mobile Money Account Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="e.g Pantang Francias"
            name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This can be name used in registering the Mobile Money</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="network">Mobile Money Network</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="network" id="network" aria-describeby="networkHelp" [(ngModel)]="network" required>
                  <option value="airtel-gh">Airtel Mobile Money</option>
                  <option value="tigo-gh">Tigo Cash</option>
                  <option value="mtn-gh">MTN Mobile Money</option>
                </select>
        <small id="networkHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We currently support only Airtel Mobile Money</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number">Your Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="number" name="phone_number" class="form-control" id="phone_number" placeholder="e.g 0269201707" aria-describeby="phone_numberHelp"
            [(ngModel)]="phone_number" required maxlength="10">
        <small id="phone_numberHelp">The Mobile Money number payment will come from. It should belong to you.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="internet_package">Internet Package</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="internet_package" id="internet_package" aria-describeby="packageHelp" [(ngModel)]="internet_package"
            required>
                  <option value="1gig">1 Gig - 30 Days - 5 Cedis</option>
                  <option value="3gig">3 Gig - 30 Days - 10 Cedis</option>
                  <option value="10gig">10 Gig - 30 Days - 30 Cedis</option>
                </select>
        <small id="packageHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Choose your package</small>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary text-white" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reviewPurchase">Review Purchase</a>
    <!-- Review Purchase Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="reviewPurchase" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reviewPurchase" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="reviewPurchase">Review your Purchase</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Name: <strong>{{ f.value.name}}</strong></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Mobile Money Network: <strong>{{ f.value.network }}</strong></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Your Number: <strong>0{{ f.value.phone_number }}</strong></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Internet Package: <strong>{{ f.value.internet_package }}</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="lead text-center text-danger" *ngIf="!f.valid">
                        You have not fully completed the form. Go back and fill all the fields.
                    </p>
                    <p class="lead text-center" *ngIf="f.valid">
                        Proceed below if details above is correct.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Make Payment</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

However..

Immediately I do `ng build --prod`, I get this error:

Exactly what kinda error is it complaining about? Why is it complaining now, but not when I run the `ng serve`?

> ERROR in
>   ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (18,151): Property 'name' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
>   ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (23,104): Property 'network' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
>       ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (32,161): Property 'phone_number' does not exist on type
>   'AppComponent'.
>       ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (37,122): Property 'internet_package' does not exist on type
>   'AppComponent'.
>       ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (18,139): Property 'name' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
>       ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (23,46): Property 'network' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
>       ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (32,38): Property 'phone_number' does not exist on type
>   'AppComponent'.
>       ERROR in ng:///home/khophi/Developments/Angular/BuyUnifi/src/app/app.component.html
>   (37,46): Property 'internet_package' does not exist on type
>   'AppComponent'.

**Edit**

This is my `AppComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { PurchaseService } from './purchase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  busy: boolean;

  constructor(public purchase: PurchaseService) {}

  onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  };
}
```

Comment: Do they all exist on the component?

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov edited to add my `AppComponent`

Comment: That's your answer. You have to explicitly declare all those properties in your component. JIT allows such a trick while AOT does not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this line, you're attempting to bind to a variable called `name`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="e.g Pantang Francias"
        name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

There is no `name` variable in your component, hence the error.

Comment: Same goes with all the other properties it is complaining about.

Answer (score 5):

I got it by declaring property of `[(ngModel)]` in TS file's class which implements OnInit.

HTML file

```html
 <input type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        id="customerName"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
        placeholder="e.g Pantang Francias"
        name="name" 
        [(ngModel)]="name_test">
```

TS File

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name_test: String = "";
}
```

Just focus on `name_test` you'll get your answer.

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 2):

in your app.component.html you have created a form with input fields and you have declared models to binds your input field data.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="e.g Pantang Francias"
        name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">

<select class="form-control" name="network" id="network" aria-describeby="networkHelp" [(ngModel)]="network" required>

<input type="number" name="phone_number" class="form-control" id="phone_number" placeholder="e.g 0269201707" aria-describeby="phone_numberHelp"
        [(ngModel)]="phone_number" required maxlength="10">
```

These models- name, network, phone_number need to be added in app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, we can see, you have not declared variables name, network, phone_number, etc. in the AppComponent file.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same problem recently, so maybe this could be helpful for you.

1. add `FormsModule` to your `app.modules.ts` by

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
....
    FormsModule
  ],
...
})
```

2. declare those variables on your ts file by adding
   `name!: string;` or other type by `network!: any;`